# Rewriting a symbolic expression as linear combination of others

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve something which may not actually be too complicated (mathematically), but I'm a bit lost and want to do this wich SymPy's aid. I

Given are two variables `X`, `Y` (these are symbolic, I do not have access to any values) and known constants `a`, `b`, ..., `g`. In a piece of existing software that I cannot change, from these

```
X' = a * X + b
Y' = c * Y + d
Z' = e * X * Y + f
```

are calculated. In another different piece of existing software that I cannot change,
I have different values, a similar calculation is done. I am greatly simplifying this for purposes of this question, but to get the idea:

```
X' and Y' like above
Z_ = (a * x + b) * ( c * y + d) - g
```

To bridge between `Z'` and `Z_`, I want to express z_ as a linear combination of `X'`, `Y'`, `Z'`, and 1:

```
Z_ ==  * X' +  * Y' +  * Z' + .
```

**How can I solve this for , , ,  with Sympy?**

I know I could probably avoid Sympy, expressing each of the variables `X'`, `Y'`, `Z'`, `Z_` as linear combinations of `X`, `Y`, `X*Y`, and 1, and doing matrix algebra But since my problem actually is more complicated and its details likely to change in the future, I would really appreciate some software assistance.

Comment: Do you mean x, y in Z_ or X, Y?

Comment: Maybe [solve_undetermined_coeffs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.solve_undetermined_coeffs) does what you are looking for.